# Updating Materui LinearProgressWithLabel progress value with my own Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to Update Material UI LinearProgressWithLabel progress value with my own Value. I am getting my value from on upload progress in the Axios.post method and it is the percent value below which is a number.

```
<Grid item xs>
   <LinearWithValueLabel value={percent}/>
</Grid>
```

And then the Progress Bar:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import LinearProgress, { LinearProgressProps } from '@material-ui/core/LinearProgress';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

interface Props {
  value: number;
}

const LinearProgressWithLabel: React.FC<Props> = ({ value }) => {
  return (
    <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
      <Box width="100%" mr={1}>
        <LinearProgress variant="determinate" />
      </Box>
      <Box minWidth={35}>
        <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">{`${Math.round(
          value,
        )}%`}</Typography>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
});

const LinearWithValueLabel: React.FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [progress, setProgress] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress((prevProgress) => (prevProgress >= 100 ? 0 : progress));
    }, 800);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <LinearProgressWithLabel value={progress} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default LinearWithValueLabel;
```

But I am getting this error in the console:

```
Warning: Material-UI: you need to provide a value prop when using the determinate or buffer variant of LinearProgress
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the value prop.

```
const LinearProgressWithLabel: React.FC<Props> = ({ value }) => {
return (
  <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
    <Box width="100%" mr={1}>
      <LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={value} />
    </Box>
    <Box minWidth={35}>
      <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">{`${Math.round(
        value,
      )}%`}</Typography>
    </Box>
  </Box>
 );
}
```

Comment: No, Im not: <LinearProgress  value={percent} />

Comment: @that's your LinearWithValueLabel tho... Check your LinearProgressWithLabel

Comment: Check the updated answer. Your weren't including the value prop in the LinearProgress from material-ui.

Comment: I added that but 'value is still not updating'. This ```<LinearWithValueLabel value={percent}/>``` has a red line under value : 'Type '{ value: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }''

Comment: Your LinearWithValueLabel component does not have any argument (prop) in its declaration, so it doesn't recognize any value prop. Declare it the way you did for LinearProgressWithLabel